# LaTeX: disable or turn off hyperlinking for table of contents?

Tags: latex, tex, hyperref, tableofcontents

I want a table of contents, but I don't want each line to be a clickable hyperlink.  How do I do this?

Details:
I am using the `\anothertoc` command from the shorttoc package to "import" the TOC from another document.  Works fine, except that all the links for the imported TOC are broken (obviously)...  so, I want to de-linkify them.

Not sure whether this is relevant, but the TOC that I'm importing is from a document that uses the hyperref package.  I have a feeling that hyperref is making the TOCs hyperlinked, but I can't find any option for the hyperref package to disable hyperlinking for TOCs.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider the `linktoc` parameter when importing the package with for instance
`\usepackage[linktoc=none]{hyperref}` or
`\usepackage[linktoc=page]{hyperref}`.
You can refer to paragraph 5.13 of the manual at https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/hyperref-doc.pdf

Comment: `linktoc=none` will turn-off the hyperlinks from **all** tables of contents, which might not be wanted in the spirit of importing another toc. This does not allow the have the toc of the current document with hyperlinks and the imported toc without.

Answer (score 0):

How are you "importing" the toc?

I'd have a look at the hyperref manual at : http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html

The simple solution would be to turn off hyperlinking in the document toc that you are importing, though I realize that might not be possible.

Comment: I'm using the \anothertoc command from the shorttoc package to import the TOC.

Comment: If you need hyper linking in the other document, turn hyperref off for run latex run, complete the document that doesn't need hyperref, then turn hyperref back on.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [Normadize's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323919) based on `\NoHyper` working well with the shorttoc package:

```
{\protect\NoHyper%
\anothertoc{other-document}{Toc from other document}{1}
\protect\endNoHyper}%
```